# How to create destination path for node.js stream pipe?

Tags: javascript, node.js, stream, coffeescript

I would like to pipe a node.js stream into an output file. But I would also like to make sure that output destination exists before I start piping. The problem with the following code is that event handlers from pipe are added late (after `assurePath` callback is called) so data is not available anymore in the input stream. I would not like to use sync fs methods to not block the whole process.

```
assurePath = (path, callback) ->
  path = path.split path.sep
  i = 0
  async.eachSeries path[1...path.length-1], (segment, callback) =>
    i++
    p = path[0..i].join path.sep
    fs.exists p, (exists) =>
      return callback() if exists
      fs.mkdir p, callback
  ,
    callback

saveStream = (filename, stream, callback) ->
  path = fullPath filename
  assurePath path, (error) ->
    return callback error if error

    finished = false
    stream.on('error', (error) ->
      return if finished
      finished = true
      callback error
    ).pipe(
      fs.createWriteStream path
    ).on('finish', ->
      return if finished
      finished = true
      callback()
    ).on('error', (error) ->
      return if finished
      finished = true
      callback error
    )
```

Comment: Have you tried [pausing your stream](http://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_readable_pause) right before calling `assurePath ` and then [resuming it](http://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_readable_resume) in callback? Can't test it right now, but I think it may help you.

Comment: Added it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try [pausing your stream](http://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_readable_pause) right before calling `assurePath` and then [resuming it](http://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_readable_resume) in callback:

```coffee
saveStream = (filename, stream, callback) ->
  stream.pause()
  path = fullPath filename
  assurePath path, (error) ->
    stream.resume()
    # ...
```

Calling `.pause()` will cause your `stream` to stop emitting data events. Any data that becomes available will remain in the internal buffer. Calling `.resume()` in `assurePath` callback will cause your `stream` to resume emitting data events.